# Email Marketing - How do I display a certain image based on a particular contact field value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, email

We use Constant Contact and we'd like to send our subscribers a visual scorecard.

For example, if "John Smith" has a 4-Star Google rating (which we store as a contact variable), then we'd want to display a particular image of 4 stars.
This is a simplified example, but is there a way to dynamically display certain images based on a contact variable/field? Given the requirements, we will need to use an HTML email template.

I'm open to any and all ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Define dynamically.  Do you want to run JavaScript from within an email?  That won't work.  Do you mean to send a custom email with the appropriate star rating or whatever catered to each user?  That's more possible.  Right now, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used Constant Contact but all have a way of working around things. Just like dynamic content for first name (`$SUBSCRIBER.FIRSTNAME`), you can send an image path in the database.

**For example:**

Save 5 images:

- image 1 - 1starUser
- image 2 - 2starUser
- image 3 - 3starUser
- image 4 - 4starUser
- image 5 - 5starUser

Each user will have a star rating and the database will have different links for each user. For example:

First name: John 
Last Name: Smith
StarRating: 5starUser

Now all you do is add HTML for the image with the correct merge tag:

```
<img src="YOURWEBSITEURL/images/$SUBSCRIBER.StarRating" width="" height="" style="display:block;" />
```

Hope the above works and answers your question.